# Error using R magick package

Tags: r, image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to save a jpeg picture in png format using the magick package in R and I'm facing an error.

Below is the error that I get using this code:

```
library(magick)

testPic <- "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/42/President_Roosevelt_-_Pach_Bros.tif/lossy-page1-165px-President_Roosevelt_-_Pach_Bros.tif.jpg"

image <- image_read(testPic)
image_info(image)
image_convert(image, format = "png", depth = NULL)
Error in magick_image_write(image, format, quality) : 
  Magick: profile 'icc': 'RGB ': RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG `' @ warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1656
```

Comment: That is just a warning, not an error, and it should not affect the processing. You should still get an output image. PNG does not like getting an sRGB color profile added to a grayscale image.

Comment: This was an error and there is no output png image

Comment: It works fine for me from the command line as: `convert https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/42/President_Roosevelt_-_Pach_Bros.tif/lossy-page1-165px-President_Roosevelt_-_Pach_Bros.tif.jpg tmp.png`. 
convert: profile 'icc': 'RGB ': RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG `tmp.png @ warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1665. I get a warning only and the file is created. So perhaps your R is misinterpreting the warning as an error. Also it might be a version issue with either ImageMagick or libpng. What are your versions of each? I am using IM 6.9.9.37 & libpng 1.6.34

Comment: When I load magick there is a message that says 'Linking to ImageMagick 6.9.9.14' there is nothing about libpng. I reported this as a bug https://github.com/ropensci/magick/issues/116

Comment: You can check the version of libpng by using `convert -list format` and then looking at the line for PNG.

Comment: Try adding -quiet to your command: `convert -quiet https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/42/President_Roosevelt_-_Pach_Bros.tif/lossy-page1-165px-President_Roosevelt_-_Pach_Bros.tif.jpg tmp.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [bug in imagemagick](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/884). The workaround is to add `strip = TRUE` to `image_read()`:

```
library(magick)

testPic <- "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/42/President_Roosevelt_-_Pach_Bros.tif/lossy-page1-165px-President_Roosevelt_-_Pach_Bros.tif.jpg"

image <- image_read(testPic, strip = TRUE)
image_info(image)
image_convert(image, format = "png", depth = NULL)
```

I'll try to ping upstream again to fix this.

Comment: That would be nice, it's a bit frustrating to have the first command in a tutorial fail. Thanks